# What methods are there to present tactical combat results?

Tags: games

Our game has extremely simple combat, basically an army of 500 would beat an army of 100 with a loss of 100 units. No actual tactical results are given aside from choosing an (optional) initial war spell to use.

Because it is so predictable and abstract, it's hard to make the UI come alive. As far as I can tell, these are the ways one could present it:

- Like Advance Wars (armies on both sides of the screen, firing at each other) e.g. https://36.media.tumblr.com/c72e518980149e8254024aa32a8169eb/tumblr_inline_nuh32aXiAy1sdn55s_540.jpg
- CCG-style, with army "cards" taking damage.
- Small armies battling on screen. (e.g. http://mmoraw.com/images/stories/MMO/Browser2D/Feudon/Feudon-%2811%29.jpg)
- A simple battle report (Win/Loss, X killed, Y lost)
- Show armies on either side with numbers ticking down (e.g Pirates!, Defender of the Crown)
- Text based animated battle report (Reveal one paragraph of text at a time)

Have I missed any possibilities? What would you recommend for making the game come alive more?

(limitations: typically only one "army type", but up to 9 in theory, battle runs automatically)

---

For the last UI in the list, it would look something like:

`[Icon] The armies of A clashes with the armies of B
[Icon] 100 elves and 100 dwarves are attacking the 100 orcs of B
[Icon] The army of B is annihilated! 100 orcs lost
[Icon] A counts his dead: 50 elves and 50 dwarves lost
[Icon] B manages to escape!`

Each line being revealed one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of this section is to present simple and clear some results. For me, a table with the battle report (Win/Loss, X killed, Y lost) seems the best option.

Of course, it is better if you add some charts or graphics that synthesize the results in a visual manner.

Comment: One thing is that the experience becomes a bit "flat". Battle is a rare occurrence and simply presenting the result might convey the feeling that it is rather unimportant and non-dangerous, when it's the opposite way around (it's the primary method of permanently killing other players' characters). Animations and visualizations might more strongly paint an extended and important struggle than just displaying the result.

Answer (score 1):

In one hand, the CCG approach would give it a look if it was like *Kantai Collection* or *Mosters Warlord* and it's a really good one because the cards give visual feedback of what's going on and so the player can understand easier how the system handles stuff.

In the other hand though, you could have a simple scoreboard at the end of the battle showing basics stats like as you said: Win/lost, X killed, Y lost; some icons here and there showing the teams; and nice animations. You can even include loot the player got from that fight, if your game has that feature.

**Edit**: forgot the conclusion!

I would recommend using those two approaches so your game provides full feedback of what IS and what HAS happened. Animations are the core of games(*well, text based games leave that to your imagination so yeah..*) and they don't harm!